# Why do the process.cpu_percent() of each process not equal psutil.cpu_percent()

Tags: python, linux, windows, macos, memory

I'm trying to find the most CPU intensive processes in my Python program.

```
print(psutil.cpu_percent())

for p in psutil.process_iter():
    try:
        print(p.cpu_percent())
    except (psutil.NoSuchProcess, psutil.AccessDenied, psutil.ZombieProcess):
        pass
```

Essentially, I need to get the percentage of CPU being used for each process (which I think is what I'm printing) but what's weird is that psutil.cpu_percent() returns something from 10-18ish % but all of the processes say that they are using 0.0% of my computer's CPU.

Answer (score 1):

This is an interesting question, so I looked into the `psutil` [docs](https://psutil.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) a bit. The 0.0% problem is an expected one. One noted solution is to set an interval of at least 0.1: `p.cpu_percent(interval = .1)`.

Assuming you have a multi-core CPU, comparing `psutil.cpu_percent(interval = .1)` against the cpu percents for individual processes might not be as straightforward as expected.

There may be processes that have threads running on multiple cores. `Process.cpu_percent` will add the totals across cores together, so you may get cpu percent values greater than 100%.

You should still be able to spot the cpu intensive processes by looking at the processes with higher values, but it'll be harder to gauge their usage against the full capacity of a multi-core CPU.

If you're on a Linux distro, the `psutil` team wrote this [script](https://github.com/giampaolo/psutil/blob/master/scripts/cpu_distribution.py) that avoids the issue by charting processes by processor core. It can probably be modified to include cpu percent. As it is, it'll show process name by core and only charts up to 8 cores. It doesn't look like it'll work for Windows or macOS, though.